# Github-pull request conflicts

Tags: github, pull-request

I Created a pr and it was approved. As Build got failed, I was unable to merge with master branch. So, I made some changes and committed code to feature branch. Still I am unable to merge with master branch because of the issue:"" **There is 1 issue preventing you from merging this pull request.
You still need a minimum of one successful build before this pull request can be merged.**""

To merge my changes with master, can I continue with my existing pr or do I have to create a pr?

Comment: You shouldn't need a new PR. When you made the last change, did you push your commit? If you're using CI/CD, did the build/pipeline pass?

Comment: I merged my commit lasttime. But build failed.

Comment: So you merged your last PR to master and the master branch pipeline failed? If so, then yes, you need a new PR because you need to merge a new branch to master again.